# A guy walks into a bar. His buddy laughs and says, "Don't worry, I didn't see it either."

Tags: meaning, jokes, humor

> A guy walks into a bar. His buddy laughs and says, "Don't worry, I didn't see it either.

What is the meaning of this joke? What makes it funny? (Is it supposed to be funny?)

I saw this joke in the [mood message](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mood_message) of a British guy.

It is a kind of bar joke but there is usually a connection. (For example: a guy with dyslexia walked into a bra).

I didn't get this one. Can it be a [meta-joke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-joke)?

Comment: A guys literally walks into (crashes into/hits his head on) a bar (long piece of metal).

Comment: @Jim: Wow. I didn't see it :)

Comment: That makes three of you apparently. ;-)

Comment: You got two decent answers, I don't think this question deserves to be deleted. They both explain the double meanings of *bar* and *walk into*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The joke is that the guy walked into a bar: a straight piece (as of wood or metal) that is longer than it is wide and has any of various uses (as for a lever, support, barrier, or fastening),rather than into a barroom. Definition one rather definition five in Merriam:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bar

Answer (score 4):

In most "walks into a bar" jokes, the bar is a pub or tavern. Here, the person has *walked into a bar*, meaning he has collided with some sort of rod. It is a meta-joke in that it plays with the conventions of a well-known class of jokes, and is a pun on the dual meaning of the word *bar*.

Comment: And the dual meaning of _walk into_.